# React component is calling memo function twice

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

If i create a React component like so:

```
import { useMemo } from "react";

let id = 0;

function updateLogAndGetId() {
  const newId = id++;
    console.log(newId);
    return newId;
}

export const MyComponent = () => {
  const componentId = useMemo(updateLogAndGetId, []);
  console.log("outside", componentId);
  return <li>{componentId}</li>;
};

render(<><MyComponent /><MyComponent /></>)
```

The HTML output will be:
1
3

the console output would be:
0
1
2
3

Why is it that the updateLogAndGetId is invoked 4 times, when only two components are added to the dom?

Are there any way to ensure that updateLogAndGetId is only invoked once pr component?

Here as a sandbox with a working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-dream-rti4tp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The React `StrictMode` renders components twice on development (not production)

```
// your index.tsx :
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import * as ReactDOMClient from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = ReactDOMClient.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

you can remove it and test your console.log again

```
// your index.tsx :
import * as ReactDOMClient from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = ReactDOMClient.createRoot(rootElement);

// render your App component without the StrictMode :
root.render(
    <App />
);
```

more about [React StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html)

Comment: Wow great spot!

I found this behaviour working on a nextjs app.
Console.log statements get's turned off for the double renders in Chrome (which is not the case in the virtual log in codesandbox) . which caused me to be even more confused. Thank you for your assistance